# Mapping P4java Exceptions To Jax-RS

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jax-rs, perforce, p4java

I'm developing a Web Service Application that interact with Perforce server (connect,submit,delete,sync....) and my problem is that JBOSS AS7 server blocks me every time  i tried to lunch the service.this is my classes
please My friends i need some help
Best Regards

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import com.perforce.p4java.exception.ConnectionException;
@Provider
public class ConnectionExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<ConnectionException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConnectionException exception) {


          return Response.status(Response.Status.SEE_OTHER).build();
    }
}

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ConnectionException extends com.perforce.p4java.exception.ConnectionException implements Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public ConnectionException() {

        super();
    }
    public ConnectionException(String msg)   {
   super(msg);
    }
    public ConnectionException(String msg, Exception e)  {
   super(msg, e);
    }
}
```

and the server exceptions

```
15:23:27,855 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."PerforceTestConnect.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."PerforceTestConnect.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "PerforceTestConnect.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class com.maher.webService.WebService with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.PerforceTestConnect.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/perforce/p4java/exception/P4JavaException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2499) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1811) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.perforce.p4java.exception.P4JavaException from [Module "deployment.PerforceTestConnect.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.perforce.p4java.exception.P4JavaException means that jboss is unable to find the p4java jar file in your application's classpath. Did you place it into the libraries section of your war file?

Comment: yes i added the jar to build path @Bryan Pendleton